# Adding configuration to Symfony Flex project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to define some custom config values for my Symfony Flex application (which will be filled with .env values), but all the docs assume I'm using a bundle, like this one: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html

I have a custom namespace, something like 'Foo\Bar', so I though the Extension class should be called `src\DependencyInjection\FooBarExtension.php`, but that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can load my custom config?

Edit: the following solution worked:

- Put config file `foo.yaml` in `config/packages`
- Put `FooExtension.php` in `src/DependencyInjection`
- Add following code to `Kernel.php`

  ```
  public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
  {
      $container->registerExtension(new FooExtension());
      parent::build($container);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Symfony 4.1, you should be able to register a new extension in your `AppKernel` by overriding the [`build()` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L423). There, you can register your [extensions](https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Extension.html) which in turn enable you to parse your own configuration files.